# vim - NERDTree open in new window / instance of VIM?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I use gvim and I use NERDTree and i'm wondering if there is a way for me to open a file from NERDTree in a new instance / window of VIM? I know how to open in a new tab but I can't figure out how to open it in a completely new window / instance of vim.

Comment: There's no builtin command for that but nerdtree's documentation explains clearly how to add your own command, did you try anything?

Comment: @romainl hm okay I will read the docs right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can launch a file in a separate GVIM instance via this:

```
:silent execute '! gvim' shellescape(filename, 1)
```

For Windows, use `!start` instead of `!`.

---

NERDTree has great documentation on how to extend it. See `:help NERDTreeKeymapAPI` and `:help NERDTreeMenuAPI`.